# Why is my template that is compiled using $compile() a different object when using Karma than when I run my app?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, karma-jasmine

I'm attempting to test a directive(component). The directive is an attempt at creating a news feed. The news feed directive adds posts(which are other directives) as child elements every time the item attribute of the news feed component is changed.

```
angular.module('rabbitBrainApp')
.directive('newsfeed', ['$http', '$compile', function ($http, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,

        link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
            var parent_scope = scope.$parent;

            scope.$watch(attrs.item, function (item) {
                if (item !== undefined) {
                    var template = "<youtube-post src='" + item + "'/>";
                    var post = $compile(template)(parent_scope);
                    post.appendTo(element[0]);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the directive works when used in my app but when I try to test it I get an error "Object [object Object] has no method 'appendTo'".

```
it('should add post to the news feed every time the item attribute is changed', inject(function ($compile) {
    element = angular.element('<newsfeed item="item"></newsfeed>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.item = '//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/E9I2HUeu8CU';
    scope.$apply();

    var youtubeElements = element[0].children;

    expect(youtubeElements.length).toBe(1);
}));
```

What I could establish from debugging is that for some reason `$compile(template)(parent_scope);` returns a JQLite object when using Karma and an Array when using it in an app.

If anyone can shed some light on this it would be great. Thanks in advance

Comment: And what happens if you use `element.append(post);`?

Comment: `appendTo` is not mentioned in the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: That did the trick for both scenarios, thanks @ivami. So my understanding is that the method I was using is not part of JQLite. The question still remains why it's an Array in the one scenario and a JQLite object in the other? Shouldn't a directive be isolated? I ask because I don't want my test to pass but then have the component break in my app.

Comment: That is why I posted the solution as a comment and not an answer :) I am not entirely sure, though I suspect it has something to do with JQuery selectors returning something that looks like an array even when there is only one result, while $compile returns just an element. I don't know if that is the cause of what you're seeing though.

Comment: Cool :), will dig a bit more.